# Toggle style.display for <p> in javascript button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am trying to make a button on my page that toggles between the style.display of a paragraph.

This is because i want it to only show up when the button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Oscar Li</title>
        <h1>Oscar Li</h1>
    </head>

  <body>


    <p1>Junior Developer</p>
      <!--creates the cube-->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/myFunction.js"></script>
  <p2 id="abMe">"this is my text"</p2>
  <p><button2 type="button" onclick= "myFunction" >About me</button></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("abMe");
  var displaySettings = x.style.display;
  if (displaySettings === "none") {
    displaySettings = "inline-block";
  } else {
    displaySettings = "none";
  }
}
```

css

```
p2{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
```

Only toggles the paragraph to hide but doesnt toggle it back on to show

Comment: add the codes into HTML/JS/CSS code snippet instead of adding them separately.

Comment: You're updating the local variable `displaySettings` instead `x.style.display`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Don't just make up tags like `p1` and `p2`. While HTML is vary forgiving you can't just add these new tags without defining their behavior. If you are going to use custom elements make sure to close them with the same tag, eg `<p1></p1>`

Step 2: Use CSS to adjust styling and javascript to toggle the css.

```js
/*The modern way to assign a click handler*/
document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  /*Get the element*/
  var x = document.getElementById("abMe");
  /*Toggle the show class*/
  x.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
#abMe {
  position: relative;
}

/*Hide element without the show class*/
#abMe:not(.show) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Junior Developer</p>
<p id="abMe">"this is my text"</p>
<p><button type="button" id="toggle">About me</button></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->
    <title>Oscar Li</title>
    <h1>Oscar Li</h1>
    <style>
        #abMe {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <p1>Junior Developer</p>
        <!--creates the cube-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/myFunction.js"></script>
        <p id="abMe">"this is my text"</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">About me</button>
</body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("abMe");
        var displaySettings = x.style.display
        if (displaySettings === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, explain what you're doing. Just posting code isn't helpful nor does it agree with  community guidelines

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).